# Suspend/Hibernate works only a couple of times

Tags: linux, arch-linux, hibernate, suspend

Usually, after restarting, I can run

```sh
systemctl suspend
```

once or twice, after which, it gives me an error:

```
Failed to suspend system via logind: There's already a shutdown or sleep operation in progress
```

Kernel: Zen 5.4.1

Systemd:

```
systemd 244 (244-1-arch)
+PAM +AUDIT -SELINUX -IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK -SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

KDE: 5.17.4

The only thing I can find in

```sh
journalctl -r
```

is this:

```
Dec 17 12:21:36 anarchy kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
Dec 17 12:21:36 anarchy kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Dec 17 12:21:36 anarchy kernel: Restarting kernel threads ... done.
Dec 17 12:21:36 anarchy kernel: pool 16: cpus=0-7 flags=0x4 nice=0 hung=0s workers=6 idle: 2480 2377 2398 2499 2225
Dec 17 12:21:36 anarchy kernel:     delayed: disk_events_workfn
Dec 17 12:21:36 anarchy kernel:     in-flight: 1633:thermal_zone_device_check BAR(1633)
Dec 17 12:21:36 anarchy kernel:   pwq 16: cpus=0-7 flags=0x4 nice=0 active=1/0
Dec 17 12:21:36 anarchy kernel: workqueue events_freezable_power_: flags=0x86
Dec 17 12:21:36 anarchy kernel: Showing busy workqueues and worker pools:
Dec 17 12:21:36 anarchy kernel: Freezing of tasks failed after 20.002 seconds (0 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=1):
Dec 17 12:21:36 anarchy kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... 
Dec 17 12:21:36 anarchy kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Dec 17 12:21:36 anarchy kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Dec 17 12:21:16 anarchy kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.014 seconds
Dec 17 12:21:16 anarchy kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Dec 17 12:21:16 anarchy systemd-sleep[2497]: Suspending system...
Dec 17 12:21:16 anarchy systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Dec 17 12:21:16 anarchy systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Dec 17 12:21:16 anarchy polkitd[652]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2482:991538 (system bus name :>
Dec 17 12:21:16 anarchy NetworkManager[488]: <info>  [1576599676.5555] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Dec 17 12:21:16 anarchy NetworkManager[488]: <info>  [1576599676.5553] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  e>
Dec 17 12:21:16 anarchy polkitd[652]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2482:991538 (system bus name :1.>
Dec 17 12:15:16 anarchy kernel: audit: type=1100 audit(1576599316.511:56): pid=2401 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 msg='op=PA>
```

The freezing tasks bit is the only hopeful thing there is, but I don't know where to go from here.

**EDIT:**
Here's another occurrence of the same problem

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2019-12-06 01:50:36 AST, end at Tue 2019-12-24 21:42:36 AST. --
Dec 24 21:42:36 anarchy kernel: audit: type=1100 audit(1577238156.125:124): pid=11806 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 msg='op=>
Dec 24 21:42:36 anarchy audit[11806]: USER_AUTH pid=11806 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 msg='op=PAM:unix_chkpwd acct="anton">
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Demoted 10 threads.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 649 of process 649.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 784 of process 649.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 786 of process 649.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 898 of process 674.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 1501 of process 968.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 1523 of process 1002.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 4277 of process 946.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 7395 of process 885.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   hw_ptr       : 912251656
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   appl_ptr     : 911378041
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 620652323646996>
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 62065232364>
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 87787
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 1000000
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 44100
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 88200
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   rate         : 44100
-- Logs begin at Fri 2019-12-06 01:50:36 AST, end at Tue 2019-12-24 21:42:36 AST. --
Dec 24 21:42:36 anarchy kernel: audit: type=1100 audit(1577238156.125:124): pid=11806 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 msg='op=>
Dec 24 21:42:36 anarchy audit[11806]: USER_AUTH pid=11806 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 msg='op=PAM:unix_chkpwd acct="anton">
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Demoted 10 threads.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 649 of process 649.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 784 of process 649.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 786 of process 649.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 898 of process 674.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 1501 of process 968.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 1523 of process 1002.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 4277 of process 946.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 7395 of process 885.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   hw_ptr       : 912251656
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   appl_ptr     : 911378041
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 620652323646996>
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 62065232364>
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 87787
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 1000000
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 44100
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 88200
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   rate         : 44100
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stream       : PLAYBACK
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: Slave: Hardware PCM card 0 'HDA >
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 620652323646996>
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 7763 of process 1016.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 62065232364>
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 87787
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 1000000
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 44100
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 88200
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   rate         : 44100
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stream       : PLAYBACK
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: resolution: 256
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: max_dB: 0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: min_dB: -51
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: Control: PCM Playback Volume
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: Soft volume PCM
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_dump():
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: Most likely this is a bug in the>
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_delay() returned a value>
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully demoted thread 11581 of process 1033.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   hw_ptr       : 912251592
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   appl_ptr     : 911369771
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 620652323646996>
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 62065232364>
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 87787
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 1000000
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 44100
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 88200
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   rate         : 44100
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stream       : PLAYBACK
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: Slave: Hardware PCM card 0 'HDA >
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 620652323646996>
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Demoting known real-time threads.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 62065232364>
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 87787
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 1000000
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 44100
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 88200
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   rate         : 44100
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stream       : PLAYBACK
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: resolution: 256
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: max_dB: 0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: min_dB: -51
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: Control: PCM Playback Volume
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: Soft volume PCM
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_dump():
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: Most likely this is a bug in the>
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy pulseaudio[649]: E: [alsa-sink-92HD75B3X5 Analog] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_avail() returned a value>
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy kernel: Restarting kernel threads ... done.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy kernel: pool 16: cpus=0-7 flags=0x4 nice=0 hung=0s workers=6 idle: 11765 11722 11553 11795 11297
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy kernel:     delayed: disk_events_workfn
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy kernel:     in-flight: 10578:thermal_zone_device_check BAR(10578)
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy kernel:   pwq 16: cpus=0-7 flags=0x4 nice=0 active=1/0
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy kernel: workqueue events_freezable_power_: flags=0x86
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy kernel: Showing busy workqueues and worker pools:
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy kernel: Freezing of tasks failed after 20.002 seconds (0 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=1):
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... 
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Dec 24 21:42:29 anarchy kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Dec 24 21:42:09 anarchy kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.034 seconds
Dec 24 21:42:09 anarchy kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Dec 24 21:42:09 anarchy systemd-sleep[11793]: Suspending system...
Dec 24 21:42:09 anarchy systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Dec 24 21:42:09 anarchy systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Dec 24 21:42:09 anarchy polkitd[631]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:11778:12988701 (system bus nam>
Dec 24 21:42:09 anarchy NetworkManager[492]: <info>  [1577238129.2075] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Dec 24 21:42:09 anarchy NetworkManager[492]: <info>  [1577238129.2074] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  e>
Dec 24 21:42:09 anarchy polkitd[631]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:11778:12988701 (system bus name >
Dec 24 21:25:48 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Supervising 10 threads of 8 processes of 1 users.
Dec 24 21:25:48 anarchy rtkit-daemon[678]: Successfully made thread 11581 of process 1033 owned by '1000' RT at priorit>




tionAgent, locale en_CA.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)


t path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_CA.UTF-8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I still can't write comments so I write here:

1. Is it "just" arch linux or has it some modifications like "manjaro" or "Antergos" does/(did)?

2.
The journal is cutted after *sleeping: no e> ??* (at this lines):

> Dec 17 12:21:16 anarchy NetworkManager[488]:   [1576599676.5553]
>   manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  e> //?????
>
> Dec 17 12:21:16 anarchy polkitd[652]: Unregistered Authentication
>   Agent for unix-process:2482:991538 (system bus name :> //??????

I suspect it to have some files needed to be written - maybe you have a nfs connected or something the network is writing/communicating with?

Am happy to help with more detailed information after you added the full error message to determine what task gets "freeze" staying busy. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you. That does make sense. I've posted a full log this time, starting from when I executed `systemctl suspend`.

Comment: @Anton Thanks for your repli and your edit. Please answer 1. and 2. - the log is still cutted off. That is made visible with the ">" symbol. To see what is following and cutter of you have to scroll to the right in the terminal (with arrow keys f.e.) and add it to the answer.